# Composition of two right exact functors is also right exact

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, functors

I have a question regarding composition of exact functors in $Abelian$ categories.
lets say I have the two right exact functors:
$F: \mathscr C_1  \to \mathscr C_2$,
$G: \mathscr C_2 \to \mathscr C_3$.

Im wandering whether the composition of the two functors $G \circ F$ is also right exact?

I'm asking because it sounds right by intuition, but when I go by the definitions its not really clear:
If I understand correctly, a right exact functor transfrom a SES $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ to an exact sequence $F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C) \to 0$.

But now, i left with an exact sequnce, ant not a SES, so  how do I know that the functor G transform that exact sequence into the exact sequence
$G(F(A)) \to G(F(B)) \to G(F(C)) \to 0$?

Comment: An additive functor $F$ is right exact in your definition iff for all exact sequences $A\to B\to C\to 0$, the sequence $FA\to FB\to FC\to 0$ is still exact. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292037/1179406 for a proof in the dual case of left exact functors.

Comment: A functor is right exact iff. it preserves finite colimits. With this perspective, it is obvious that a composite of right exact functors is right exact